# Informix how to find all users in a database?

Tags: database, informix

When I create a user in a database it is not showing in 'sysusers' table of the database until the user is granted with any database level privilege , how to identify a user with no privileges in a current database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sysusers](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_077.htm?lang=en) system catalog table only shows who holds database-level access privileges.

If you want to check users that have been granted a role but don't hold database-level access privileges you can cross the [sysroleauth](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_057.htm?lang=en) with the [sysusers](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_077.htm?lang=en) system catalog table:

```
    SELECT  grantee
    FROM    sysroleauth
    MINUS
    SELECT  username
    FROM    sysusers;
```

> When granting a role to a user, or to another role, it will not validate if this exists.
>
> It will only give a error if you attempt to grant a role to yourself, unless you have [DBSECADM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0843.htm%23ids_sqs_0843?lang=en), or if you include the [WITH GRANT OPTION](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0125.htm?lang=en) keywords in a [GRANT](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0127.htm?lang=en) statement that assigns a role to another role.

For the follow up question:

> is it legitimate to grant privilege to the user who is not granted any db level privileges?

Yes, it's legitimate. If you create a role and assigned it has the default to a user that does not have a db level privilege it will be granted an implicit connection to the database.

And in this case the user will only show up on `sysusers` after you issue the [GRANT DEFAULT ROLE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0841.htm?lang=en) statement.

> Other cases:

If a user is created using the [CREATE USER](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1821.htm?lang=en) statement you must look into the [sysuser](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sec.doc/ids_am_041.htm?lang=en) database.

If you mean creating objects on behalf of others schemas that don't have a user on the database you need to get all those owners.

You can find the system catalogs tables that store owners by querying:

```
SELECT UNIQUE t.tabname
FROM systables t
    INNER JOIN syscolumns c ON (t.tabid = c.tabid)
WHERE c.colname = 'owner' AND t.tabid < 100
ORDER BY 1;
```

But probably you want to take only a look into [systables](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_072.htm?lang=en), [sysobjstate](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_047.htm?lang=en) and [sysprocedures](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_053.htm?lang=en).

Try the following:

```
SELECT  owner
FROM    systables
WHERE   tabid > 99
UNION
SELECT  owner
FROM    sysobjstate  
UNION
SELECT  owner
FROM    sysprocedures
MINUS   
SELECT  username  
FROM    sysusers;
```

Bear in mind that some internal users, like `sqlj`, `sysibm` and `sysproc`, can appear because the `sysprocedures` is not filtering internal ones.

If you want to see all the **OS** users that don't have database-level access privileges you can, in UNIX, do:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE os_users(
    username    CHAR(32),
    password    CHAR(1),
    uid         INT,
    gid         INT,
    gecos       CHAR(256),
    home_dir    CHAR(256),
    shell       CHAR(32)
) WITH NO LOG;

LOAD FROM '/etc/passwd' DELIMITER ':'
   INSERT INTO os_users;

SELECT  username
FROM    os_users
MINUS
SELECT  username
FROM    sysusers;
```

You can filter the **OS** users by the `uid`, normally **0** is the `root` user and the range **[1-99]** is reserved for special system users

Then some system begin **UIDs** for non-privileged users at **100**. Others, such as Red Hat, begin them at **500**, and still others, such Debian, start them at **1000**.

Comment: thanks a lot Mr.Henriques , I would like to eloborate the point where I got confused is, while granting a role to a user 1) if a user does not exist in sysusers table of current database and exists in sysuser database  I can grant a role 2) if user doesn't exist in either of the databases then also  I can grant a role. please clarify it.

Comment: @starc check the edit on top of the answer if it is enough.

Comment: Thanks once again master Henriques for the edit , I don't want to trouble you much but I have uncertainty in granting role to user i.e, is it legitimate to grant privilege to the user who is not granted any db level privileges or the user who is not known to server even though informix accepts this with out  error, please help with this @henriques.

Comment: @henriques , over these days  I got one more doubt , suppose I create a default user ,by using "create default user with properties" how to identify a default user I mean in which table the default user entry exists ? please clarify.

Comment: @starc `create default user with properties` will not create a user per se. It will only create a default set of properties, like the skeleton used by unix/linux. Then you can create omitting the properties. You really should open a question for each doubt, not only the answer is more objective but, also, other users that have the same doubt can find the answer easier.

Comment: @henriques , thanks a million once again , I felt my doubt is not so materialistic as it is and everything in my primary question is about users so , I kept in this question itself , but next time considering your suggestion  I will open a new question for each doubt.